# Receiving a TypeError in FF and Chrome for JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, typeerror, deprecated

Please help...I have tried everything to correct this error in Firefox and Chrome.  I am receiving the current error when I run my function.  "TypeError: obj1.options is not a function". I have tried many things including even trying to change the onclick function to a JQuery .click() function and also placing between a JQuery Document.ready function.  It works just fine in IE, but throws the TypeError in other browsers. Actually I get multiple Type Errors one for the AddMember Function and one for the Remove Member.  This may be old deprecated JavaScript.  Any help that is offered is appreciated.  Thanks

```
function RemoveMember(idx, idx2){
//centralizes code to remove selected items from a MULTIPLE SELECT (listbox).
//loops "backward" to maintain valid indexing counters while removing items.

var obj = idx;
var obj2 = idx2;
var nCount = 0;
    nCount = obj.options.length - 1;        
    for ( nCount; nCount > -1; nCount -- ) {
        if ( obj.options(nCount).selected == true ) {               
            var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
            oOption.text = obj.options(nCount).text;
            oOption.value = obj.options(nCount).value;
            obj.options.remove(nCount);
            //JJK added add back to avail list 
            obj2.add(oOption);                          
        }               
    } //for 

    //sort both listboxes
    sortOptions(obj2);
    sortOptions(obj);       
}
```

---

Here is the complete html file so you can see it all.  We essentially have two list boxes and there are two images with click actions to Add or Remove the list items from the left first listset to the second listset.

```html
<!-- #include file = "../include/permissions.inc" -->
<!-- #include file = "../Include/adovbs.inc" -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<%
CheckPermissions pManagePFI, True
Dim sType, PFIName
Dim objSup, osRS, ret, iSupID

sType = Request.QueryString ("type")
pfid = Request.Form ("pfid")
'Set Type
if sType = "SV" then
 sType = "2"
elseif sType = "DC" then
 sType = "1"
end if
'Get PFI Name 
if not pfid = "" then
 set objPFI = Server.CreateObject("LAS.NET.CPFI")      
 PFIName  = objPFI.GetName(clng(pfid))         
 set objPFI=nothing   
end if   

function selOptions()
 Response.Write "<option value='0'>select</option>"
 if sType = "2" then
  Response.Write "<option selected value='2'>Servicer</option>"
 else
  Response.Write "<option value='2'>Servicer</option>"
 end if
             
 if sType = "1" then
  Response.Write "<option selected value='1'>Document Custodian</option>"
 else
  Response.Write "<option value='1'>Document Custodian</option>"
 end if
end function

function GetSupporters()
   set objSup = Server.CreateObject("LAS.NET.CSupporter") 
   Dim sSupportName, getType
   
   if sType = "2" then
    getType = "Servicer"
   elseif sType = "1" then
    getType = "Document Custodian"
   end if
   ret = objSup.GetSupportList(cstr(getType), clng(pfid)) 
    
   Set osRS = UnPersistRS(ret)
   if not osRS.EOF then   
    osRS.MoveFirst 
    osRS.Filter = "bActive = True"
     Do while not osRS.EOF
      sSupportName = osRS.Fields("sSupport_Name").Value
      iSupID = osRS.Fields("iSupport_ID").Value
      Response.write "<option value='" & iSupID & "'>" & sSupportName & "</option>"
      osRS.MoveNext
     loop
   end if
   set osRS=nothing
   set objSup=nothing
end function

function GetPFISupporters()
 if not pfid = "" then 
  set objPFI = Server.CreateObject("LAS.NET.CPFI") 
        dim osRS 
  if sType="2" then
   ret = objPFI.GetSupporters("Servicer",clng(pfid))
  elseif sType= "1" then
    ret = objPFI.GetSupporters("Document Custodian",clng(pfid))
  end if
  If len(ret) <> 0 then
   Set osRS = UnPersistRS(ret)

   if not osRS.eof then 
    Do while not osRS.eof 
     sSupportName = osRS.Fields("sSupport_Name").Value
     iSupID = osRS.Fields("iSupport_ID").Value
     Response.write "<option value='" & iSupID & "'>" & sSupportName & "</option>"
     osRS.MoveNext
    loop
   end if
  end if
  set osRS=nothing
  set objPFI=nothing
 end if
end function%>

<title>FHLB</title>

<script language="javascript">



function SelectValue(idx, val){
//centralizes code to loop index values in SELECT and highlight
//appropriate item.

var obj = idx;
 var nCount = 0;
 var nCounter = 0;
  nCount = obj.options.length;
  for ( nCounter = 0; nCounter < nCount; nCounter ++ ) {
   if ( obj.options(nCounter).value == val ) {  
     obj.selectedIndex = nCounter;
    }
   }
   obj.value = obj.options( obj.selectedIndex ).value ; 
}

function OneSelected(idx){
//function to search a fieldset, and determine whether any checkboxes
//have been selected.
var oRows = idx.children(0).children(0).children //the only child of the fieldset is the TABLE.
var nCount = idx.children(0).children(0).children.length;
var nCounter = 0;
var ret = false;
 for ( nCounter = 0; nCounter < nCount; nCounter ++ ) {
  if ( oRows(nCounter).children(1).children(0).checked == true ) {  
   ret = true;
   break;
  }
 }
 if ( ret == true ){
  return true;
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
}

function Validate() {
 //alert("Attempted save");
 
 var obj = document.frmFHLBGlobal.MemberList ; 
 var nCount = 0; 
 var nCounter = 0; 

 nCount = obj.options.length; 
 for ( nCounter = 0; nCounter < nCount; nCounter ++ ) { 
  obj.options(nCounter).selected = true; 
 } 
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.action="process_AssignSupporter.asp";
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.submit();
}

function Refresh() {
 var obj = document.all.selType;
 obj.value = obj.options( obj.selectedIndex ).value;
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.action = "AssignSupporter.asp?type=" + obj.value;
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.submit();
}

function AddMember(idx1, idx2){
//centralizes code to loop index values in SELECT and highlight
//appropriate item.
var obj1 = idx1;
var obj2 = idx2;
var nCount1 = 0;
var nCounter1 = 0;
var nCount = 0;
  //add entries to the assigned box
  nCount1 = obj1.options.length;
  for ( nCounter1 = 0; nCounter1 < nCount1; nCounter1 ++ ) {
   if ( obj1.options(nCounter1).selected == true ) {     
    var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
    oOption.text = obj1.options(nCounter1).text;
    oOption.value = obj1.options(nCounter1).value;
    obj2.add(oOption); 
   }   
  } 
  //remove entries from available box  
  //loops "backward" to maintain valid indexing counters while removing items.
  nCount = obj1.options.length - 1;  
  for ( nCount; nCount > -1; nCount -- ) {   
   if ( obj1.options(nCount).selected == true ) {       
    obj1.options.remove(nCount);   
   }
  }
  
  //sort both listboxes
  sortOptions(obj2);
  sortOptions(obj1); 
}


function RemoveMember(idx, idx2){
//centralizes code to remove selected items from a MULTIPLE SELECT (listbox).
//loops "backward" to maintain valid indexing counters while removing items.

var obj = idx;
var obj2 = idx2;
var nCount = 0;
 nCount = obj.options.length - 1;  
 for ( nCount; nCount > -1; nCount -- ) {
  if ( obj.options(nCount).selected == true ) {    
   var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
   oOption.text = obj.options(nCount).text;
   oOption.value = obj.options(nCount).value;
   obj.options.remove(nCount);
   //JJK added add back to avail list 
   obj2.add(oOption);       
  }    
 } //for 
 
 //sort both listboxes
 sortOptions(obj2);
 sortOptions(obj);  
}

//jjk sort add V2.3.2
function sortOptions(listbox) {
 
 //get listbox values into arrays 
 var arrValues = new Array()
 var arrText = new Array()
 var obj = listbox;
 var nCount = 0;
 var nCounter = 0;
 nCount = obj.options.length;
 for ( nCounter = 0; nCounter < nCount; nCounter ++ ) {      
  arrText[nCounter]= obj.options(nCounter).text;  
  arrValues[nCounter] = obj.options(nCounter).value;      
 } 
 
 var x, y, holder, temp_text1, temp_text2;
 // The Bubble Sort method.
 for(x = 0; x < arrText.length; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < (arrText.length-1); y++) {
    temp_text1 = arrText[y];
    temp_text2 = arrText[y+1];
      if(temp_text1.toUpperCase() > temp_text2.toUpperCase()) {
        holder = arrText[y+1];
        arrText[y+1] = arrText[y];
        arrText[y] = holder;
        //do same for values array to keep their indexes together
        holder = arrValues[y+1];
        arrValues[y+1] = arrValues[y];
        arrValues[y] = holder;
      }
    }
  }

  // Update the select box list.
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < arrValues.length; i++) {
   if(listbox.options[i] == null) {
     var oOption = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
   oOption.text = arrText[i];
   oOption.value = arrValues[i];   
   listbox.options[i] = oOption;
   } 
   else {
     listbox.options[i].text = arrText[i];
     listbox.options[i].value = arrValues[i];
   }
 }
} //jjk sort end

function goPFI(){
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.action ="ViewPFI.asp";
 document.frmFHLBGlobal.submit();  
}

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style/<%=application("DistrictCode")%>.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- #include file = "../include/head.inc" -->
<p>
<table align="center" valign="middle" width="50%" border="1" class="InnerTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="tableheader" width="100%">
         <center><font class="tableheadertitletext">Add Supporter for <%=PFIName%></font></center>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="center">    
     <form name="frmFHLBGlobal" method="Post" action="process_AssignSupporter.asp">
     <input type="hidden" name="pfid" value="<%=pfid%>">
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     
     <input type="hidden" name="Test">
     <tr>
     <td align="center">
           
      <fieldset><!------list name and type-------->
      <table class="InnerTable" width="100%" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td class="InnerTableTextSmall">
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <b>List Type:</b>&nbsp;
            <select name="selType" onchange="Refresh()">
             <%=selOptions%>
            </select>
            </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </fieldset>
      
      <fieldset><!------listbox select-------->
      <table class="InnerTable" width="100%" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td width="45%" align="center" class="InnerTableTextSmall">
        <b>Available<b><br>
         <select name="MainList" MULTIPLE style="width: 200" size="15" ondblclick="AddMember(document.frmFHLBGlobal.MainList, document.frmFHLBGlobal.MemberList);">
          <%
          'if len(trim(strOptions)) > 0 then
           Response.Write GetSupporters()          
          'end if
          %>
         </select>
         
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center" valign="middle">
         <img src="../images/<%=application("DistrictCode")%>/add2.gif" name="Add Member(s)" id="Add" onclick="AddMember(document.frmFHLBGlobal.MainList, document.frmFHLBGlobal.MemberList);"> 
         <img src="../images/<%=application("DistrictCode")%>/remove.gif" name="Remove Member(s)" id="Remove" onclick="RemoveMember(document.frmFHLBGlobal.MemberList, document.frmFHLBGlobal.MainList);"> 
        </td>
        <td width="45%" align="center" class="InnerTableTextSmall">
         <b>Currently Assigned<b><br>
         <select name="MemberList" MULTIPLE style="width: 200" size="15" ondblclick="RemoveMember(document.frmFHLBGlobal.MemberList);">
          <%=GetPFISupporters()%>
         </select>
         
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
      <table class="InnerTable" width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
       <td align="center">
        <img src="../images/<%=application("DistrictCode")%>/save.gif" name="Save" id="Save" onclick="Validate()"> 
        <img src="../images/<%=application("DistrictCode")%>/cancel.gif" name="Cancel" id="Cancel" onclick="goPFI()"> 
       </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </fieldset>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table> 
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="sType" value="<%=sType%>">
  </form>
<!-- #include file = "../include/foot.inc" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `obj.options(nCount)` -> `obj.options[nCount]`

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? It seems pretty clear to me. `obj.options` is not a function, so don't treat it like a function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm fairly new to JavaScript and trying to upgrade a system that was built before modern browsers came into play.  I figured it was not a function, but did not know how to fix the issue.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj.options(nCount)
```

should be

```
obj.options[nCount]
```

---

`obj` is an [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) object. `HTMLSelectElement` doesn't have an `options` method, so the following is incorrect:

```
obj.options(nCount)    // XXX
```

`HTMLOptionsCollection` objects do have an `options` property, which is documented as follows:

> Returns a [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) containing the set of `<option>` elements contained by this element.

[`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) has two methods:

> - `item(index)` - returns the specific node at the given zero-based index (gives null if out of range)
> - `namedItem(name)` - returns the specific node with the given DOMString (i.e., string) id. Returns null if no such named node exists.

That means you should be using

```
obj.options.item(nCount)
```

`HTMLOptionsCollection`'s [parent class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) says

> In JavaScript, code that accesses `HTMLCollection` object, in order to get an item of the given `HTMLCollection`, the square bracket syntax can be used instead of directly calling the `item()` or `namedItem()` methods. Numeric values in the square brackets will work the same way as `item()`, string values will work the same way as `namedItem()`.

That means you could also be using

```
obj.options[nCount]
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.  There are many areas, where I will need to replace this code, but this helps a lot and allows me to understand the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to fix using regex-based search and replace.

Comment: Thanks the replacing of parenthesis ( ) with brackets [ ] worked.  Really appreciate the fast response as well.